# How can I remove this if condition from my view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, model

Here's the view:

```
    @if (stream.StreamSourceId == 1)
    {
        <img class="source" src="@Url.Content("~/Public/assets/images/own3dlogo.png")" alt="" />    
    }
    else if (stream.StreamSourceId == 2)
    {
        <img class="source" src="@Url.Content("~/Public/assets/images/twitchlogo.png")" alt="" />
    }
```

Basically, I use a Model property to determine what image to render.

I **know** that the correct solution would be to create a property on the model called `SourceImageUrl (string)` and use that property as the source url for the image.

I would then transfer this conditional operation to the model.

My question is, how can I do this if I'm using DataAnnotations for validation? Any suggestions?

```
public class StreamModel
{
    // This is the ID that has the value of either 1 or 2.
    public int StreamSourceId { get; set; }

    // How can I move the logic from the view, to here, and set the value accordingly?
    public string SourceImageUrl { get; set; }    
}
```

Comment: is stream available in your controller ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not do something like this?

```
public string SourceImageUrl
{
    get
    {
        switch (StreamSourceId)
        {
            case 1: return "~/Public/assets/images/own3dlogo.png";
            case 2: return "~/Public/assets/images/twitchlogo.png";
            default: return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to move your logic into the model so your view will be similar to this

```
    <img class="source" src="@Url.Content(stream.SourceImageUrl)" alt="" />
```

and you model will be

```
public class Model
{
    private string[] m_images;

    public Model()
    {
        m_images = new[] { 
               "~/Public/assets/images/own3dlogo.png", 
               "~/Public/assets/images/twitchlogo.png" 
               };
    }

    public string SourceImageUrl
    {

        get { return m_images[StreamSourceId]; }
    }
}
```

If you don't like array you can replace it with a more intelligent collection: Dictionary , HashSet, ecc